# ¿Cómo puedo instalar una aplicación desde google play en un emulador de Android Studio?

Tags: android, android-studio, google-play

Estoy desarrollando una aplicación que se complementa con Instagram en Android, pero cuando quiero instalar Instagram en el emulador para hacer pruebas, desde google play no me deja.

Estoy trabajando con una imagen de android 4.4 KitKat api level 19.

Comment: Para poder hacer esto el link que te voy a comunicar es para poder ejecutar esto en un emulador instalado en tu pc:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=kvsK_Pw6ldg

Answer (score 2, accepted):

El archivo .apk lo puedes obtener descargandolo directamente desde la playstore, en internet puedes encontrar varias opciones para realizar esto, por ejemplo:

https://apps.evozi.com/apk-downloader/

y estas son las instrucciones para instalarlo en el emulador usando Windows:

- Ejecutar el emulador.
- Iniciar consola para linea de comandos. Run -> escribir cmd, moverse al directorio  platform-tools dentro del directorio del SDK.
- Pegar el archivo APK en el folder 'android-sdk\tools' o 'platform-tools'.
- Escribir el siguiente comando para instalar el apk en el emulador:

**adb install [ruta del archivo.apk]**

Comment: ¨Muchas gracias por la respuesta @Elenasys !!